# Bootstrap popover with jquery append

Tags: jquery, append, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm having problems with Bootstrap popover when I insert it with jquery append.
See here http://jsfiddle.net/mT76T/300/!

Is this not suppose to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `$("#blob").popover({offset: 10});` after the append.  It needs to exist in the DOM before you can do anything with it...

http://jsfiddle.net/mT76T/301/

An alternative is to use appendTo so that you are returned the new element that you are creating, and you can attach the popover directly to that...

http://jsfiddle.net/mT76T/302/